# Excel 2016 for MacとOffice365 Proplus(windows)でのVBAの挙動の差

Tags: vba

WindowsのOffice365 ProplusとExcel 2013では動くVBAがMacのExcel 2016 for Macでは動きません。
サンプルとして掲載されていた以下のコードなのですが、以下の個所で「`実行時エラー５ プロシージャの呼出し、または引数が無効です`」となります、Mac版の制約か何かなのでしょうかご教示下さい。

```
Set NewM = CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)…

Sub AddMenu()
    Dim NewM As Variant, NewC As Variant
    ''(1)[新しいメニュー]というメニューを作成します
    Set NewM = CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    With NewM
        .Caption = "新しいメニュー(&C)"
    End With

    ''(2)作成したメニューに2つのコマンドを登録します
    Set NewC = NewM.Controls.Add
    With NewC
        .Caption = "1行目の処理" ''1つ目コマンド名
        .OnAction = "Action_Row" ''実行するマクロ
        .FaceId = 541
    End With
    Set NewC = NewM.Controls.Add
    With NewC
        .Caption = "1列目の処理" ''2つ目コマンド名
        .OnAction = "Action_Column" ''実行するマクロ
        .FaceId = 542
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Mac版のVBAは、無保証です。
動いたら運が良かったと思う程度。